# Storing a N-ary Tree in a Binary File

Tags: c#

Good morning,

I wrote a very simple n-ary tree structure which stores in each node a string, an integer and a list of other nodes. Since the tree is built recursively and some operations must be made to place each node in its place, I found it is faster to serialize the structure once and deserialize it every time I run my program. The problem is that deserialization takes about 4 seconds, which isn't too much but it would be nice if it could be reduced... Does anyone know a clever way to store/load a tree like this one in/from a binary file (using `BinaryReader/Write`)?

Thank you very much.

Comment: A code example would be nice.

Answer (score 0):

When you serialize you have the option to do a binary serialization. At least when using the serialization classes that come with .NET. So when you say you're serializing, what are you using?